# Moving child directive from template to compile fn breaks scope connections

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have nested directives, both creates new scopes. To preserve original content I decide to move child directive to compile function of parent directive. This move breaks connection between scopes, could someone explain me why? Thanks

jsfiddle: (remove template from parent directive to see the issue)
http://jsfiddle.net/luckylooke/uDkd3/9/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('parent', function directive() {
return {
    compile: function(elm){
        elm.append("</br> Appended <div child></div>");
    },
    template:"</br>From template <div child></div>",
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.who = "parent";
        $scope.message = "Text message";
        //console.log($scope);
    }
};
}).directive('child', function directive() {
return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<div class="child">child with {{$parent.message || "NO message!"}}</div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.who = "child";
        //console.log($scope);
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878830/angularjs-isolated-scope-for-directives-without-own-template#answer-23138385) in [Angularjs isolated scope for directives without own template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878830/angularjs-isolated-scope-for-directives-without-own-template):

> [...] only elements in a template for the directive will be bound to
> the isolated scope created by that directive. If you don't use a
> template - content of the element, on which the directive is declared,
> will bind as if isolated scope was not there.

Here is what your scope hierarchy looks like with a template:

[image]

... and here is what it looks like without one:

[image]

### A Solution

Use `transclusion` to inject elements from your view into `parent` without using `compile`:

```
.directive('parent', function directive() {
  return {
      transclude: true,
      template:"</br><div ng-transclude></div>From template <div child></div>",
      scope: {},
      controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.who = "parent";
          $scope.message = "Text message";
      }
  };
})
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ib33jK3NeDYjfZkZiqdT?p=preview)

Here the `child` directive is again an actual child of the `parent` directive. Notice too that the transcluded content appears in another scope which is a sibling of `parent`'s isolate scope:

[image]

Comment: I have problem with this transclusion aproach, because I would like to leave original content in its position. Like: <div mydirective> content </div> >>become>>  <div mydirective> content <div>elements from template</div></div>. Any simple way to achieve this? :)

Comment: I'm not seeing how this isn't what's achieved with transclusion. Can you update your question a bit?

Comment: Sorry I didnt write the comment clearly. After transclusion original content is placed inside <div ng-transclude><span ng-scope>content<span></div>. Do I need those elements? Or could I bypass them somehow. I was wondering about transclusion function in directive link function, but I dont think this could does the thing. Hope I am clearer now :)

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to avoid using `ng-transclude` in the directive's template, you can insert the cloned content manually in the link function ([example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vyFqy3nN6VzwZrNCMiuO?p=preview)).

Comment: Thanks this is final acceptable solution, thank you very much for support, really appreciated your time ;)