# Isolated Scope View binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have been working with isolated scope directives for a little time and a question came in mind watching it's behavior:

Why can't i bind variables that i define inside the directive inherited scope directly to the view?

Let me show an example on this code pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLKjrv

When i create a new $scope variable inside the directive controller and i try to bind it on the view, it does not works.
By the other hand, when i bind that variable on a html that comes from the template directive attribute, it does works.

Check out the code:

```
<body ng-app="isolated-test-app">
<section ng-controller="isolatedTestCtrl">
    <article>
      <h1>test1</h1>
        <div isolated-directive binding-from-attr="test">
            <span ng-bind="test"></span>
            <span ng-bind="test2"></span>
        </div>
      <h1>test2</h1>
        <div isolated-directive-number-two binding-from-attr="test">
        </div>

    </article>
</section>
```

```
angular.module('isolated-test-app', [])

.controller('isolatedTestCtrl', function isolatedTestCtrl($scope){
    $scope.test = 'Binded from parent controller';
})

.directive('isolatedDirective', function isolatedDirective(){

    var directive = {
        scope: {
          bindingFromAttr: '=',
        },
        controller: function directiveController($scope){
           $scope.test2 = 'Binded from directive controller!';
        },
    };

    return directive;
})

.directive('isolatedDirectiveNumberTwo', function isolatedDirective2(){

    var directive = {
        scope: {
          bindingFromAttr: '=',
        },
        template:'<span ng-bind="bindingFromAttr"></span>\
                  <span ng-bind="test2"></span>',
        controller: function directiveController($scope){
           $scope.test2 = 'Binded from directive controller!';
        },
    };

    return directive;
})
```

> test1
>
> Binded from parent controller
>
> test2
>
> Binded from parent controller
>
> Binded from directive controller!

I was expecting the result of test2 on test1.

Why does that happens?

Comment: I feel the answer's going to have something to do with transclusion

Comment: \*edit\* I take that back, yes they are :/

Comment: It is weird, the binding only works inside the template and not on the view :/

Comment: I'm quite curious about this. It will work if you remove the scope property object completely from the directive definition... but I don't know why you can't have that and also bind to properties created by the controller.

Comment: Here's a solution. This syntax makes the binding optional, seems to fix the issue: `scope: { bindingFromAttr: '=?bind' }` I don't really get why though. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign

Comment: Simplified codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doppjZ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs isolated scope for directives without own template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878830/angularjs-isolated-scope-for-directives-without-own-template)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between **directive template** and the **directive's element's contents** with regards to what scope applies.

In **isolate scope** (`scope: {}`) directives, the isolate scope applies to the template, but not to the contents. The contents have the same scope as the directive's parent. Also, note, that the contents would be replaced by the template, if the template is defined. To use the contents in addition to the template requires "transcluding" (`transclude: true`) (this is, however, outside of scope for this answer).

If you are confused, you could always check `$scope.$id` to see which scope applies:

```
<div>parent scope: {{$id}} (will be 2)</div>

<isolate-scope>
   contents of isolate scope directive: {{$id}} (will also be 2)
</isolate-scope>

<isolate-scope-with-template>
   contents will be replaced with the template
</isolate-scope-with-template>
```

```
.directive("isolateScopeWithTemplate", function(){
   return {
     scope: {},
     template: "template: {{$id}} (will NOT be 2)"
   }
})
```

(of course, the actual `$id` could be different)

In **child scope** (`scope: true`) directives, the scope that applies to the content is actually the same that would have applied to the template (same here - the template would replace the contents if it exists, unless you transclude).

Now, **to answer your question**:

The first `<span ng-bind="test2"></span>` binds to a non-existent `$scope.test2` in the parent scope and so it is empty.

But the `<span ng-bind="test2"></span>` in the template of `isolatedDirectiveNumberTwo` binds to the isolate scope of that directive, which defines `$scope.test2 = 'Binded from directive controller!'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess base on experiment in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwjjBw

so for test 1, the directive scope doesnt have test/test2 since the dom object is belong to controller. Hence in order to update it you have to use

```
$scope.$parent.test2 = "" ;
```

and for test 2, as the template is created as part of directive hence the dom object is belong to directive and also accessible by controller ( I guess $compile adding this into controller scope/watch).

You can also see that test1 doesnt have any watcher as there is no binding happen.

Answer (score 0):

Now i get the whole picture, as New Dev's answer stated on his answer

> In isolate scope (scope: {}) directives, the isolate scope applies to the template, but not to the contents. The contents have the same scope as the directive's parent.

So i have learned that there is a difference between directive contents and template and how the scope is inherited on isolated scopes.
For my application setting the scope to true solved entirely my problem.

Also, kwan245's solution is a real good work-around of this issue.

Both answers cleared my mind, many thanks to New Dev and kwan245 :)