# How to access an isolated scope within a directive that is not using a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I set a controller on an element, that element and its children have access to that controller's scope. This makes sense.

However, when I add a directive with an isolated scope to an element (as an attribute), I would expect that element and its children to have access to the isolated scope, but they do not.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="testMod" ng-controller="ParentController">
  <div id="div1" ng-controller="MyController">
    <a href="#" ng-click="doit()">MyController</a>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" my-directive>
    <a href="#" ng-click="doit()">MyDirective</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('testMod', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.doit = function() {
        console.log('ParentController scope')
      }
    }])
    .directive('myDirective', [function() {
      return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'MyController'
      };
    }])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.doit = function() {
        console.log("MyController scope");
      };
    }]);
})();
```

When I click on `#div1`'s link, `MyController scope` is output, as I expect.

When I click on `#div2`'s link, I expect the same due to the isolated scope I added on the directive, but instead, `ParentController scope` is output.

So, what elements are using the isolated scope? What does it apply to? Can I give `div[my-directive]`'s children access to it somehow?

Transclude does not help me here; I want the children of `div[my-directive]` to have access to the directive's isolated scope, not the parent scope, but I cannot use a template in this case. I essentially want the controller behavior from `#div1`, but I need a `link` function in order to do some DOM manipulation on the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. I will explain here in case it helps somebody in the future.

The answer is to use transclusion, and use the `transclude()` function to bind the element's contents to the isolated scope. This can be done by setting `transclude: true` on the directive object, and using a link function to call `transclude()`, as follows:

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('testMod', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.doit = function() {
        console.log('ParentController scope')
      }
    }])
    .directive('myDirective', [function() {
      function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
          transclude(scope, function(clone) {
          element.append(clone);
        });    
      }
      return {
        link: link,
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'MyController'
      };
    }])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.doit = function() {
        console.log("MyController scope");
      };
    }]);
})();
```

How I have come to understand this is that when you set `transclude: true` on the scope, Angular removes the element's contents from the DOM. When using a template you'd use the `ng-transclude` attribute somewhere in the template to tell Angular where to insert the contents, which is where my limited understanding of transclusion ended (as I had picked up from the [Angular's Developer's Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements)).

In this case, we are not using a template, so ngTransclude is not an option, and furthermore we want to bind to the isolated scope, not the contents' original scope (the parent scope). But we can use the `transclude()` function that Angular provides to the `link()` function to set this up manually, binding the extracted DOM contents to the isolated scope.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878830/angularjs-isolated-scope-for-directives-without-own-template) gave me the answer, and I found [this section](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion-functions) of the Angular docs helpful in understanding exactly what I was doing.

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjh79/6yg6ucgf/) for playing with this.